# Заполнение нейронной сети несколькими значениями

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Всех приветствую. Наткнулся на архитектуру нейросети от Nvidia:

```
self.model = Sequential()                                      #135, 135, 3
self.model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, input_shape=(135, 135, 3)))
self.model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(1, 1)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(1, 1)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Flatten())
self.model.add(Dense(1164, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
self.model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Эта модель была сделана специально для задач автопилотов.

На вход, на 1 слой сверточной сети, она принимает изображение с размерностью 135, 135, 3 и на входе уже выдает какой-либо угол, на который должна повернуть машина (зависит от dataset'a)

Но вот вопрос:

Можно ли как-нибудь добавить вместе с изображениями - к примеру, какие-либо показания с датчиков? (расстояния и прочее)

К примеру:

У меня есть изображение, размерностью 135,135,3.

А также массив показаний с датчика, к примеру такой:

## 3 каких-нибудь датчика

[10, 0, 25]

Ну и пометка к ним, повернуть налево, к примеру.

## -25 - налево, 0 - прямо, 25 - направо

[-25]

Как мне можно объединить показания с датчиков и изображения так, чтобы после обучения нейросеть учитывала показания этих датчиков?

Comment: попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828770/how-to-concatenate-combine-features-extracted-from-a-cnn-with-other-scalar-featu)